# How to create POJOs for JSON response consisting of ordered pair with date and data?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

This is what my `JSON` looks like:

```
{
   "Meta Data":{
      "1: Symbol":"MSFT",
      "2: Indicator":"Moving Average Convergence/Divergence (MACD)",
      "3: Last Refreshed":"2019-03-08",
      "4: Interval":"daily",
      "5.1: Fast Period":12,
      "5.2: Slow Period":26,
      "5.3: Signal Period":9,
      "6: Series Type":"open",
      "7: Time Zone":"US/Eastern"
   },
   "Technical Analysis: MACD":{
      "2019-03-08":{
         "MACD":"1.5751",
         "MACD_Signal":"1.6779",
         "MACD_Hist":"-0.1028"
      },
      "2019-03-07":{
         "MACD":"1.8551",
         "MACD_Signal":"1.7036",
         "MACD_Hist":"0.1515"
      },
      "2019-03-06":{
         "MACD":"1.9574",
         "MACD_Signal":"1.6657",
         "MACD_Hist":"0.2918"
      }
   }
}
```

I tried generating `POJO`s through online tools, however, it generates a different `POJO` for each data. Since my data could potentially be of a hundred dates. I want a generic `POJO` setup that would allow me to store this data with the dates, something like a `2D` array or a `HashMap`.

Edit: I am developing an `Android` app using `Retrofit`, `Gson`.

Comment: Sorry, but a very hard to read example string isn't sufficient here. The point is: you have to come up with a clear definition (call it a "schema") of the ways your data is structured. Yes, you can use maps and lists, but what exactly is giving you trouble?

Comment: The problem I currently have is that the current setup of POJOs doesn't work. It would be helpful if someone could help me get the ordered pairs consisting of date and MACD data into a data structure like a hashmap. I don't need help with the "Meta Data" section, only the "Technical Analysis: MACD".

Answer (score 0):

When the keys are fixed (e.g. `"Meta Data"`, `"MACD"`, ...), you map the JSON Object to a POJO class.

When the keys are dynamic (e.g. `"1: Symbol"`, `"2019-03-08"`, ...), you map the JSON Object to a `Map`.

E.g. if using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson#gson):

```
class Root {
    @SerializedName("Meta Data")
    Map<String, String> metaData;

    @SerializedName("Technical Analysis: MACD")
    Map<String, Analysis> analysis;
}

class Analysis {
    @SerializedName("MACD")
    String macd;

    @SerializedName("MACD_Signal")
    String macdSignal;

    @SerializedName("MACD_Hist")
    String macdHist;
}
```